# set "Respect Language Direction" for NSLayoutConstraint by code

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

how can I set the `Respect Language Direction` property  of a horizontal constraint to 'YES' or 'NO' when the constraint is created by code like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:10.0];
```

p.s. until now I can set this property in `Interface Builder` under the constraint's item drop down list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leading / trailing respects the language direction. Left / right doesn't. You just need to use the appropriate attributes for the constraint you are making.

Comment: I already used leading/trailing in my project but the interface never flips when the constraints are setup by code (when device's language is an RTL language), in contradiction to constraints that have been created by interface builder they will flip the interface when device's language is RTL (Arabic for example).

Comment: Well all the respect language checkmark does is alternate between left/right and leading/trailing so you've either missed something or you've found a bug. Are all your constraints using leading / trailing? Any created using VFL?

Comment: i've missed something actually .. thank you so much.

Comment: @JAHelia, what did you miss? I'm having the same problem

Comment: there is nothing i missed