# how to set respect language direction for constraints created by Visual Format Language?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout

I pin some views together by constraints (using Visual Format Language) and my app works fine in left-to-right languages
but my view are mirrored in right-to-left languages. I can fix this issue by creating constraints using:

```c
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:view2
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:0]]
```

or add constraints in storyboard and uncheck Respect Language Direction for horizontal constraints.
I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807019/set-respect-language-direction-for-nslayoutconstraint-by-code) but this is not my case.
My question is can I disable Respect Language Direction when using VFL (Visual Format Language) and how? I need an small example.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSLayoutAttributeLeading` instead of `NSLayoutAttributeLeft` and `NSLayoutAttributeTrailing` instead of `NSLayoutAttributeRight`.

UPDATE

If you need explicity change direction when using visual format please note you can pass:

```
/* choose only one of these three */
   NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing = 0 << 8, // default 
   NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeftToRight = 1 << 8,
   NSLayoutFormatDirectionRightToLeft = 2 << 8
```

to `constraintsWithVisualFormat` method. Therefore something like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"some constraints"
                options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeftToRight//<------
                metrics:nil 
                  views:viewDictionary]];
```

Comment: please read my question again. I need to disable Respect Language Direction.  if I use Leading or Trailing in VFL, in fact I have enabled Respect Language Direction and my views are mirrored when language is changed. I don't want my views be mirrored when language is changed. I know how to solve this in story board or  using 'attribute:
                             relatedBy:
                                toItem:
                             attribute:
                            multiplier:
                              constant:' i need a way when adding constraints by VFL

Comment: Ok I see could you please give an example contraint in VFL that doesn't work for you? I think you could pass https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSLayoutFormatOptions as argument and especially NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeftToRight.